# Having user input variables to be used in a later equation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a program to calculate the mass of a given molecule. I have defined every element as an integer. I need to be able to type in a chemical formula like NaCl and have it print out the sum of the atomic masses of Na and Cl. So far I have things set up so that I can type in a chemical formula and it turns it into a list of elements, so if I typed in NaCl it would give me ['Na', 'Cl']. Here is the code:

```
import re
Na = 22.99
Cl = 35.45
input = raw_input()
inputList = (re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', input))
```

Firstly I need to know how to tell the computer I am inputting variables that I previously defined, not strings. Then I want to make it assign each item from the list to its own variable. Something like

```
e1 = Na
e2 = Cl
```

My main issue is that at the moment my input is treated as a string.

Comment: Take a look at Python's [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: Dictionary is absolutely what you want to use here.

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN which is why you should look at [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) if you want it to be more accurate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is a dictionary, like so:

```
atomic_wt = {'Na':22.99, 'Cl':35.45}
```

Later, when you have your inputs, you can access them in a loop:

```
for element in inputList:
    elem_wt = atomic_wt[element]
```

Comment: Ok, I like this, but it returns two separate numbers. How do I get it to add these numbers?

Comment: make a variable before the loop. Then in the loop -> variable += atomic_wt[element]

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN I am not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: @wes1099 variable = 0, then inside the for loop, variable += atomic_wt[element]

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN oh ok, I get it now. I ended up just appending elem_wt to a list before the loop restarted, then after the loop I can print the sum of that list. Now I need to figure out how to tell it to multiply the weight of an element by a number if I input something like Na2Cl...

Comment: @wes1099 Yea, I suppose I would use regex for that too. So inputList = (re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*\d?', input)), and then in the loop, elm = element if len(re.findall('\d', element)) < 1 else atomic_wt[element]*int(re.findall('\d', element)[0])

Comment: Sorry. Like this... elem_wt = atomic_wt[element] if len(re.findall('\d', element)) < 1 else atomic_wt[element]*int(re.findall('\d', element)[0])

Comment: @wes, I have to ask the uncomfortable question to help focus our feedback.  Why are you writing a program that seems to be beyond your programming skills in so many facets?  Data conversion, a running sum, and now string processing have all shown as blocking points for you.  These are basic skills one learns during an introduction to programming, but usually with less involved applications.  Would it be useful for you fill us in on your situation?

Comment: @Prune My situation is a little complicated, but basically I haven't done any programming in a long time and I have never done anything with python. Now I need to write something in python and I have a relatively small amount of time.

Comment: I see.  Okay; code like mad.  How complex does your required format go?  For instance, do you have to handle something like CH3(CH2)4(NH3) ?  Even worse, could you have nested parentheses?

Comment: If you don't have parentheses at all, it's easier: your tokens consist of (1) capital letter with an optional small letter after it; (2) integer (could be multiple digits).  Either a regular expression or a hand-coded parser can split that up quickly enough.  Post again if you get stuck.

Comment: @Prune For now I don't need to be able to handle parentheses. If I have something like CH3(CH2)4(NH3) I can either type out CH2 four times or I could type C4H8 instead of (CH2)4 for the purpose of calculating the mass of the substance. I think I have everything figured out  now, but I will definitely come back here if I get stuck. Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) functions to add up the appropriate values from a dictionary:

```
>>> elements = {'Na':22.99, 'Cl':35.45}
>>> result = ['Na', 'Cl']
>>> answer = sum(map(elements.get, result))
>>> answer
58.44
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a dictionary, you can easily take string input and handle it:

```
elements = { 'Na': 22.99,
             'Cl': 35.45
           }  # You can extend this dictionary to include more elements

print elements.get(raw_input('Enter an element symbol:   ', 'invalid'))  
"""
use the .get method to return a placeholder value, 
representing that the *input* value doesn't exist in the dictionar
"""
```